# Updating label from another function in MainWindow in QT

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am new to QT. I created an application by a wizard.  Its UI backend was created as below.

```
QTimer *timer; // NEW
void TimerSlot(); // NEW slot
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) 
    : QMainWindow(parent)

    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    //saveSetting();
    loadSettings();
    ui->setupUi(this);
//    this->layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);
    const QString time = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString();
    ui->currentDateTime->clear();
    ui->currentDateTime->setText(time);
    timer = new QTimer(this); // create it
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, TimerSlot); // connect it
    timer->start(1000); // 1 sec timer
}

void TimerSlot()
{

   ui->lbl.setText(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString());
}
```

I placed a label on UI with name `currentDateTime`. I created a timer and a function called `myFunc()` to update the time on label (`lbl`). I want to update the label (`currentDateTime`) with time on every 1 sec tick of `timer`. I connected the timer signal with a slot (`myFunc`). In `myFunc` I want to access the label to update the text with the correct time but it gives me error.

I want to know two things,

1. In this auto-creation of `MainWindow` class how can I declare `private` and `public` data and member functions,
2. How can I access this `currentDateTime` label from `myFunc()`.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this auto-creation of MainWindow class how can I declare private and public data and member functions,

You can do that in the `mainwindow.h` file.

```cpp
class MainWindow {
public:
//...
private:
//...
}
```

> How can I access this currentDateTime label from myFunc().

You cannot access it because `TimerSlot` function is not a **member-function** of class `MainWindow`. Hence you cannot access variable `ui`.

To fix this, move the `TimerSlot()` function into the `MainWindow` class:

```
class MainWindow {
//...
private slots:
  void TimerSlot();
};
```

Then define it in the `mainwindow.cpp` file:

```
void MainWindow::TimerSlot()
{
  ui->lbl.setText(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString());
}
```

Additionally, creating global objects without any reason is not recommended. I would recommend you move `QTimer *timer; // NEW` into the `MainWindow` class:

```
class MainWindow {
//...
private:
  QTimer *timer; // NEW
}
```